# Box that doesn't affect the vertical spacing of the main document

Tags: spacing, boxes

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Text A.

\vspace*{5cm}

Text B
\end{document}
```

Now I want to change this to

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewEnviron{eatnospace}{
%% Some missing code to make it work
\BODY
}

\begin{document}
Text A.


\begin{eatnospace}
Some text that doesn't move "Text B" down:

\lipsum[2]
\end{eatnospace}

\vspace*{5cm}

Text B
\end{document}
```

I.e. I want to define an environment `eatnospace` that doesn't affect the vertical space of the main document. The background is that I want to add solutions to a math test made by a colleague. In the original test there was some vertical space (e.g. `\vspace*{5cm}`) for students answers.

Now I want to write solutions into those spaces using the original source code while changing as less as possible.

How can I do this?

**Update**:

Using @David Carlisle's suggestion, I tried to define `eatnospace` like this:

```
\NewEnviron{eatnospace}{
\vadjust{\smash{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{
\BODY
}}}
}
```

But it throws an error "You can't use `\vadjust' in vertical mode."

Comment: Please don't post just snippets. It would be much more convenient if you would provide, short, but compilable test documents.

Comment: Changing as less as possible might be tricky. Note that your first snippet doesn't introduce any white space.

Comment: the first snippet if you make it in to a document will add 3cm at the end, after `other text` is that what you intend?

Comment: `\vadjust{\smash{\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{some text here}}}`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: Sorry, see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `\vadjust` doesn't make sense after you clarified your question (this is why a **good** Minimal Working Example is important: your original question has everything on the same paragraph, which is why David Carlisle suggested that you use `\vadjust` which is only useful in horizontal mode. With your clarified question it is clear that you most likely intend to use this environment in vertical mode.)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewEnviron{eatnospace}{
        \par\noindent\smash{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\BODY}}\par\vskip-\baselineskip
}

\begin{document}
Text A.


\begin{eatnospace}
Some text that doesn't move ``Text B'' down:

\lipsum[2]
\end{eatnospace}

\vspace*{6.5cm}

Text B

\begin{eatnospace}
        This happens if you over flow
        \[ f(b) - f(a) = \int_a^b f'(x) ~dx \]
        \lipsum[1]
\end{eatnospace}

\vspace*{4cm}

Text C

\newpage
Text A.

\vspace*{6.5cm}

Text B

\vspace*{4cm}

Text C

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

#### Alternative Solution

It seems a bit silly to me, however, to smash a `\parbox` and manually insert a `\vspace*`, when you can just tell the `\parbox` to have the correct height. While we are at it, we can also include a toggle to hide the solution, so in the future you can just have one copy of the document and use it to build both the test and the solution.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newif\ifshowsolution
\showsolutiontrue  % change to \showsolutionfalse to hide solutions
\NewEnviron{eatnospace}[1]{
        \par\noindent\parbox[t][#1]{\linewidth}{\ifshowsolution\BODY\fi}\par
}

\begin{document}
Text A.

\begin{eatnospace}{6.5cm}
Some text that doesn't move ``Text B'' down:

\lipsum[2]
\end{eatnospace}

Text B

\begin{eatnospace}{4cm}
        This happens if you over flow
        \[ f(b) - f(a) = \int_a^b f'(x) ~dx \]
        \lipsum[1]
\end{eatnospace}


Text C

\newpage
Text A.

\vspace*{6.5cm}

Text B

\vspace*{4cm}

Text C

\end{document}
```